# Why is trait implemented on a type with some trait bound not accepting functions implemented on them?

Tags: rust

I am working on the setting up a server example from the rust book. I will add the relevant parts here.

```
trait FnBox {
    fn call_box(self: Box<Self>);
}

impl<F: FnOnce()> FnBox for F {
    fn call_box(self: Box<F>) {
        (*self)()
    }
}
type Job = Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>;
```

my implementation which is slightly changed from the book. It is `FnBox` in book rather than `FnOnce()`. And I call

```
job.call_box()
```

Here `job` is of the type `Job`. But this throws an error.

```
   |             job.call_box();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: job is a function, perhaps you wish to call it
   = note: the method `call_box` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `dyn std::ops::FnOnce() + std::marker::Send : FnBox`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `call_box`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `FnBox`
```

The trait `FnBox` has been implemented on all the types with `FnOnce()` trait. So I do not understand why it says `dyn std::ops::FnOnce() + std::marker::Send : FnBox` is not satisfied.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that `FnBox` is a workaround for a limitation of older versions of Rust. In modern Rust, you can just call `job()` normally (which is, I believe, the only reason turbulencetoo's answer compiles). The book has not been updated yet.

Comment: @trentcl I was actually kind of surprised to see the `(self)()` bit work after I removed the `*self` part. Is it correct to say that the code OP is trying to write used to be impossible to express correctly in old versions of Rust (without using nightly FnBox), but is now basically a no-op in newer Rust?

Comment: The implementation of ```FnOnce()``` is currently above my understanding of my language with ```extern "rust-call"``` and all. But I am looking to it. But I am surprised at the way ```self()``` actually works here. I am assuming it doesnt have anything to do with  deref coercion. An unsized call be invoked in such a way is surprising.

Comment: @turbulencetoo Yes, exactly.

Comment: @raj You are right, deref coercion doesn't come into it: [`Box<dyn FnOnce()>` *itself* implements `FnOnce()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html#implementors) (there's no [src] link because it's implemented by a compiler hook, not in the library). Unfortunately this is not the kind of thing you can do with your own type, at least not without `feature(unsized_locals)` on nightly, but it works fine with `Box`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the implicit `Sized` bound on `F` in the `impl` for your `FnBox` trait, which makes a `Box<dyn T>` not covered under that `impl`.

You say

> The trait FnBox has been implemented on all the types with FnOnce() trait.

But actually the trait FnBox has been implemented for only all *Sized* types with FnOnce() trait. [The docs for Sized](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html) have more info about this.

A working example is:

```rust
trait FnBox {
    fn call_box(self: Box<Self>);
}

impl<F: FnOnce() + ?Sized> FnBox for F {
    fn call_box(self: Box<F>) {
        (self)()
    }
}
type Job = Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>;

let job: Job = Box::new(|| println!("gwahhh"));
job.call_box();
```

Note that I had to remove the `(*self)()` in favor of `(self)()` because you cant move an unsized type out of a `Box`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=03e09ba30547b438934815768437278e)

Comment: yes you are right. Size is implemented silently which i missed. But the fact that ```self()``` works is little surprising to me.